# If $R$ is an equivalence relation, is $R = R^3$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

If $R$ is an equivalence relation, does $R = R^3$ ?

I tried for about 40minutes to construct a relation $R$ that is an equivalence relation that when multiplied with itself twice, it will make $R = R^3$ false and haven't succeeded.

Would love to see a counter example

Comment: @walker Can you give a set of pairs that are equivalence ratio, but when multiplied 3 times to $R^3$ then $R != R^3$?

Comment: What do you call equivalence ratio?

Comment: @walkar $(x,y)\in R^2$ means that there is a $z$ such that $(x,z),(z,y)\in R$.

Comment: **Relation**, not ratio

Comment: Deleted comment and posted as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If $R$ is a reflexive relation, then $R\subseteq R^2$. In fact, if $(a,b)\in R$, then $(a,c)\in R$ and $(c,b)\in R$ is satisfied by $c=a$. Therefore $(a,b)\in R^2$.
- If $R$ is transitive, $R^2\subseteq R$. If you think about it, it is *exactly* the definition of transitivity.

For a relation $R$ satisfying both (for instance, equivalences and non-strict orderings) it holds $R^2=R$, hence $R^n=R$ for all $n\ge1$.